# How is 0.0.0.0:22 under the column local address of netstat command related to ip address?

Tags: ssh, output, netstat

I have a Ubuntu server and I connect to it from home computer using SSH. Once I connected, on the terminal of the server, netstat shows under the column "local address", 0.0.0.0:22

For example, say my ip server is 192.99.x.x (which is not in the format of local ip address), my home public address is 184.148.x.x.

How is 0.0.0.0:22 related to the ip addresses I mentioned above.

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: So, which ip addresses does 0.0.0.0:22 refer to  from Ip address I mentioned above.

Comment: Why instead of 192.99.x.x  it use 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 4):

0.0.0.0 represents all IP addresses on the machine. That means that a service listening on 0.0.0.0 is listening on every IP address on the machine. A machine can have multiple IPs for different adapters, like Ethernet, Wi-Fi, OpenVPN, etc.